# I broke SSH access to my Raspberry Pi

Tags: usb, pi-3b+, raspbian-jessie, usb-power, usb-hub

I had my Raspberry Pi 3B+ running old Raspbian Jessy. I was connecting to it by `ssh`. I have installed [`uhubctl`](https://github.com/mvp/uhubctl).

`uhubctl` is a tool which can turn off power supply for USB port.

I got

```
# uhubctl
Current status for hub 1-1 [0424:9514, USB 2.00, 5 ports, ppps]
  Port 1: 0503 power highspeed enable connect [0424:ec00]
  Port 2: 0100 power
  Port 3: 0100 power
  Port 4: 0100 power
  Port 5: 0100 power
Current status for hub 1 [1d6b:0002 Linux 4.14.50-v7+ dwc_otg_hcd DWC OTG Controller 3f980000.usb, USB 2.00, 1 ports, ppps]
  Port 1: 0503 power highspeed enable connect [0424:9514, USB 2.00, 5 ports, ppps]
```

Then I did

```
# uhubctl -a off -l 1-1 -p 1
Current status for hub 1-1 [0424:9514, USB 2.00, 5 ports, ppps]
  Port 1: 0503 power highspeed enable connect [0424:ec00]
```

and lost access to my Raspberry Pi.

What did I do? Powered off my network card or what?

Comment: You **may** get an answer here, but probably more likely to get something useful by filing an [issue on the uhubctl GitHub site](https://github.com/mvp/uhubctl/issues).

Comment: @Seamus I don't think it is `uhubctl` issue...

Comment: the NIC on the 3B+ is a USB device (lan78xx) - so, yes, you powered off the NIC - a reboot should fix that

Comment: @Dims: Regardless of whether or not it's a `uhubctl` issue (and it now seems fairly clear that it is), under the circumstances as described in your question, it would make sense to search the issues on their GitHub site.

Comment: uhubctl author here. I answered it [here](https://github.com/mvp/uhubctl/issues/491). Nothing that reboot can't fix. And this is not 3B+, perhaps 3B or earlier.

Answer (score 3):

As pointed out by Jaromanda X, the ethernet NIC on the Pi 3 (and earlier models) is integrated with the USB controller. There is a bit of a clue in the first line of that `uhubctl` output ("**5** ports").

Looking further (`lsusb` is in the `usbutils` package, which is not installed by default):

```
> lsusb
[...]
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0424:ec00 Microchip Technology, Inc. (formerly SMSC) SMSC9512/9514 Fast Ethernet Adapter
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0424:9514 Microchip Technology, Inc. (formerly SMSC) SMC9514 Hub
```

Notice the USB hub and ethernet adapter are both tagged with SMC9514. From https://www.microchip.com/en-us/product/LAN9514

> ...the industry's first fully-integrated, Hi-Speed USB 2.0 hub and
> high-performance 10/100 Ethernet controllers

I do not think the settings tweaked with `uhubctl` will persist across re-boots (although I have not used and so could be wrong).

[image]